# Swift - access object attributes - how to

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to access object attributes from a WKInterfaceController, however my lack of knowledge around Swift is starting to shine.

Lets say I make an API call and pass the response to a controller via `pushController()`. Below are some snippets of my code:

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        // I know context is an object, how to access its elements
}
```

The data in `context` looks similar to `{"user":"me","pw":"wouldntyouliketoknow","host":"google.com"}`. Will someone please let me know how i can just access `context.host`? Overtime I attempt to access the object attributes, I get error by the compiler saying something like `host is an unknown property`

Also, context can't be casted to type NSObject or AnyObject really.

Answer (score 1):

the swift compiler thinks that context is object of type Any so due to this reason you can not access properties of object directly - try to cast object of type Any to your object type like:

```
if let movie = context as? Movie {
        print("Movie: \(movie.name), dir. \(movie.director)")
}
```

or you can try UNSAFE and by me NONRECOMENDED option:

```
context.value(forKey: "name")
```

Comment: In your case, I would be required to define class `Movie`. Im trying to avoid this type of work....in JS, i would just do something like `if(context.host) ...dowork`

Comment: sorry I mean context.value(forKey: "name") - this should work

Comment: Ill give it a shot tonight, i had tried this yesterday, but was getting spammed with compiler errors. At least knowing that this is the way to access  an objects attributes is half the battle. If this is my resolve, ill mark your answer as correct

Comment: So, the original object is passed to swift via obj-c (which i think init as NSMutableDictionary) and when i try `if let tmp=context as? NSObject { print(context.value(forKey:"host"))}` I receive and error=`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. Yea, so `context.value(forKey:"host")` does work either when casting as `AnyObject`